# Is it possible to disable the IE Lync add-on with a script

Tags: plugins, lync

Our website has recently been hit by a new plugin pushed out to IE. 
The plugin is for Lync that detects phone numbers and adds a phone number link next to it. 
This is impacting our rich text editor implementation by adding the link to the data that is being saved. 
Does anyone know how to disable this plugin with some sort of a metatag or other script?

I am looking at stripping out the html that is being added when its saved, but that's a very clunky solution.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

thanks
-Scott

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer: Hiding the icon with CSS is even easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18402758/1469525

Original answer:

It doesn't appear that a meta-tag exists to disable the plugin.

Through trial and error I found that MS Lync does not recognize the non-breaking hyphen. So I wrote a jQuery plugin to replace hyphens in phone numbers with the non-breaking hyphen &#8209 character code. MS Lync IE plugin runs after the javascript completes so it won't see the phone number and won't add the icon.

More [details on my blog](http://uncommentedbytes.blogspot.com/2012/06/jquery-to-disable-ie-ms-lync-phone.html), or just see the code:

```
/* Hide phone numbers from MS Lync plugin */
/* by using non-breaking hyphens          */
/* usage: $('.phone').disableMSLync();    */
jQuery.fn.disableMSLync = function() {
  return this.each(function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/-/g,"&#8209;");
  })
}
```

Comment: It does now.  The Lync plugin looks for the .html after the page finishes loading everything.

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting ideas in the following link for doing the same with the Skype plugin - not sure if these would work for you

[Howto Remove Skype Plugin Markup with jQuery](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/751.cfm)