# Show phone number on page to load call in Lync

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3, lync

I have an application, which contains a web page which will show Phone Numbers for people.

eg. 0115 987 6543

What I would like to do is show the phone number as a link which automatically loads Microsoft Lync client to do so.

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I managed to find the answer in a thread about how to disable such a thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728521/disable-lync-click-to-call-detecting-numbers-in-a-web-page)

There is a [standardized way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728521/disable-lync-click-to-call-detecting-numbers-in-a-web-page) to markup a phone number for compatibility with VOIP/dialing programs. It uses a standard `A` anchor with a `tel:` protocol. This has the dual effect of not only disabling Lync's intrusive markup, but also providing better support for anything that knows how to dial a number (Skype) and mobile devices (both iOS and Android).

```
<p>For help, please call <a href="tel:1-800-555-1234">1-800-555-1234</a>.</p>
```

Now Lync users can still click the link, which will prompt them to "open" it with Lync, regardless of the browser they use (I've confirmed compatibility with IE9, Firefox and Chrome). This strikes me as the best of both worlds: compatibility with users' telephony application, without trouncing all over your markup and layout.