# Phone Icon in server side HTML PDF generation?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, pdf

We have a server side PDF generation which converts HTML to PDF .

However we find that the phone number exactly like this [PhoneIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta7MR.png) 
- Its strange that we actually don't deal with HTML directly when we generate this PDF , we
deal with IDN , and basis the IDN , the HTML in the DB gets converted to PDF . However there are cases where HTML is also sent from the browser directly in which case a browser side intervention looks possible .

Does anyone know what is causing this problem ? It has been noticed in IE and we came to know there is a plugin that does Phone Number to this format thingy .

Comment: Looks like Lync, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6728521/231316

Comment: Absolutely disabling that solved the problem , however its curious  case as to why it happens when we deal only with IDN's from client side . Need to check that . Thanks for the correct link .

Comment: Check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341485/how-to-make-a-html-page-in-a4-paper-size-pages